# Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle

Tags: momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Question: The uncertainty in position is equal to the uncertainty in momentum. What is the uncertainty in velocity?

What I did: I know that the uncertainty in position multiplied by uncertainty in momentum is equal to $\frac{h}{2\pi}$ As momentum is mass times velocity, and mass is constant and definite, the uncertainty in momentum is equal to the uncertainty in velocity. Thus the answer should be $$\sqrt{\frac{h}{m2\pi}}$$ However, this is incorrect. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Consider rephrasing the sentence _Uncertainty in position and momentum are equal,_ since they are two quantities of different dimensions/units.

Comment: The new version _"The uncertainty in position is equal to the uncertainty in momentum"_ is no different, it is still talking about equality of two quantities of different units. Either you have misunderstood the question or something is missing here.

Comment: But that's what the question says. @JiK

Answer (score 1):

The Heisenberg inequalities reads :

$$\Delta x \Delta p_x \geq \frac{\hbar}{2},$$
where 
$$\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi}. $$

Therefore, for a free particle, your add the expressions
$$ p_x=mv_x$$
so you get :
$$\Delta x \Delta v_x \geq \frac {\hbar}{2m}$$
you have the uncertainty on the velocity : $\Delta v_x \geq \frac{\hbar}{2m\Delta x}$

the Heisenberg inequalities relies two observables. here, $x$ and $p_x$ or $x$ and $v_x$.
Be carefull, if the particule is not free, there might be some changes.

Comment: I don't understand. I have read that the formula is $\frac{h}{2\pi}$?? Is this wrong? And your answer isn't correct either. The correct answer is $\frac{1}{2m}\sqrt{\frac{h}{\pi}}$

Comment: you don't say what is the full formula... So we cannot check. But I can tell you that my formula is correct.

Comment: ?????? What do you mean?

Comment: give the full equation. not juste one side. For instance, my formulae is $\Delta x \Delta p_x \geq \frac{\hbar}{2m}$ there is the two sides of the equation

Comment: @salix Same LHS but for the RHS its just $\frac{h}{2\pi}$

Comment: your formulae don't have the good units...

Comment: @Gummybears: Notice that $\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi}. $